# Image wont show in div when using Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have created a website and it works fine on Firefox and IE but for some reason the image won't display in my div on Chrome. The image has the correct src as it works in all other browsers. Randomly it shows everything in chrome if I rename the "product" div to something else, but then the hover effects etc of the product div won't come into effect. Here's my code:

```css
.product {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.product:hover {
  background-color: #dfdddd;
}
.tinfo {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: -80px;
  position: relative;
}
.buy {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 14px;
}
a.add2 {
  color: #e9e9e9;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #282828;
  border: 1px solid #282828;
}
a.add2:hover {
  color: #282828;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #282828;
}
```

```html
<div class="product">
  <img src="images/myImg.png" class="imgSize">
  <div class="tinfo">Product info here
    <br>$00.00
    <div class="buy"><a href="cart.php?add=product1" class="add2">Add to cart</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vvdyfqso/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```html
<div class="product">
  <img src="~/images/myImg.png" class="imgSize">
  <div class="tinfo">Product info here
    <br>$00.00
    <div class="buy"><a href="cart.php?add=product1" class="add2">Add to cart</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, turns out that Chrome didn't like the float:left on the products css so I deleted that line of code and the site still looks fine. Thanks for your help!